# Improve a working "Bulgarian Solitaire" J verb

Tags: solver, j

"Bulgarian Solitaire" is a mathematical curiosity. It is played with a deck of 45 (any triangular number will work) unmarked cards. Put them into randomly sized piles. Then, to play a round, remove a card from each pile and create a new pile with the removed cards. Repeating this step eventually yields the configuration `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` (for 45 cards), which is clearly a fixed point of the game and thus the end of the solitaire. I wanted to simulate this game in J.

After a couple of days thinking about it and some long-awaited insight into J gerunds, I came up with a solution, on which I would like some opinions. It starts with this verb:

```
bsol =: ((#~ ~:&0) , #)@:(-&1)^:(<_)
```

Given a vector of positive integers whose sum is triangular, this verb returns a rank 2 array showing the rounds of the solitaire that results. I also came up with this verb to generate an initial configuration, but I'm less happy with it:

```
t     =: 45 & - @ (+/) NB. Would work with any triangular number
cards =: (]`(]@,>:@?&t@]))@.(0&<@t)^:_
```

Given a vector `y` of positive integers, `t` returns the defect from 45, i.e., the number `45 - +/ y` of cards not accounted for in the piles represented by the argument. Using `t`, the verb `cards` appends to such a vector `y` an integer from `>: i. t y` repeatedly until the defect is 0.

Expanding `t` explicitly, I get

```
cards =: (]`(]@,>:@?&(45 & - @ (+/))@]))@.(0&<@(45 & - @ (+/)))^:_
```

I feel like this is not very brief, and maybe overly parenthesized. But it does work, and the complete solution now looks like this:

```
bsol @ cards @ >: @ ? 44 NB. Choose the first pile randomly from >: i. 44
```

Without the named verbs:

```
(((#~ ~:&0) , #)@:(-&1)^:(<_)) @: ((]`(]@,>:@?&(45 & - @ (+/))@]))@.(0&<@(45 & - @ (+/)))^:_)@>:@? 44
```

Not knowing much about J idiom, I have the same feeling about this: it's not very brief, certainly redundant (would it be better to use a local verb like `t` here, since it's repeated, e.g.?), and probably overly parenthesized. What opportunities do I have to improve this program?

Comment: I think you'll find that J-forums is a better place for questions of this kind.

Comment: Thanks. I (re-)subscribed and will lurk for a little while before posting there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve `t` with

```
t =: 45 - +/
```

Using `46 - +/` will spare you some `>:`.

You can replace `cards` with a recursive definition:

```
cards =: }.`(($:@] , -) ?)@.(0&<)
```

where, now, `cards n` produces an initial configuration with sum `n`.

In `bsol` you don't need `-&1` if you remove (`-.`) the zeroes and rearrange it like:

```
 bsol =: (0 -.~ [:  (, #) <:)^:(<_)
```

Comment: nice solution.  `(0 -.~ [:  (, #) <:)^:a:` for 2 fewer bytes :)